# Salesforce Mobile SDK iOS: WebKit error: [UIDevice macaddress]

Tags: ios, webkit, salesforce

After entering credentials and granting access, I get the following error in the output window of the iPhone simulator:

"*** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate:  -[UIDevice macaddress]: unrecognized selector..."

Any suggestion why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

In your WebViewDidFinish method, remove the web view you added as a subview to your view.